# Youtube Analytics: Filter videos only uploaded in given time period

Tags: youtube, analytics, youtube-analytics

I am totally stuck in finding a solution to this.

I am trying to easily filter the data for Yooutube videos **uploaded in given time period** to check only their Views and other metrics. Currently if I check the views in the Youtube Analytics, there are all the videos uploaded only the views in given period are considered.

Can somebody help?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a group of the videos you are looking for. On the top right of YTA, click on `Groups -> Create video group`.

Comment: yes thats actually the way how I solve it at that time, dont know if there is feature now in YouTube, but has to be done manually at that time